# index.html necessary but I'm using php

Tags: php, ajax, indexing

I'm switching from one of those web page designers to a traditional html only format ( i made a website from scratch! yay!) However, I have one index.php, the rest of the site's content is loaded into a div.  The host ( webstarts.com) forces my index to be .html extension. Could this be why none of my content is able to load?

http://rsgnaturalrearing.webstarts.com/

It seems like its not reading the files ( maybe i need to give their servers a chance to update? )

Comment: Properly PHP is not (properly) installed on your website host. Try to use `<?php echo phpversion(); ?>` to test it.

Comment: I don't see any reference to php or php files in your source code. Where are you actually trying to load or execute a php file / code?

Comment: well i thought all pages needed to be php for the ajax requests ( the loading content on to the index) I do use a php script on the contact us page...i just just switch to a host provider that uses c-panel

Comment: yes apparently host doesn't have mysql or php or anything installed lol. doesn't even have ftp, i have to upload one file at a time...

Comment: how can you determine through the browser development tools if php or mysql is installed on a site's host provider?

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite htaccess

all requests to file.html will be sent to file.php:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [NC]
```

Hope it helps

Comment: file is not visable in root directory, if i try to upload my own it says invalid file format :(

Comment: which file? '.htaccess'?? it is generally hidden by default